# Need help understanding why $Var(max(X,Y)) = Var(min(X,Y))$ if $X$ and $Y$ are iid $N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, variance

> $Var(max(X,Y)) = Var(min(X,Y))$ if $X$ and $Y$ are iid $N(0,1)$

The book solution says

- $(X,Y)$ has the same distribution as $(-X,-Y)$ since $X$ and $Y$ are iid $N(0,1)$
- it follows that $Var(max(X,Y)) = Var(min(X,Y))$

---

It make sense intuitively but I'm having trouble seeing it.

1. It make sense to me that $max(X,Y) = -min(-X,-Y)$ so for example the $max(1,4) = -min(-1,-4)$
2. Then take the variance of both sides $Var(max(X,Y)) = Var(-min(-X,-Y))$
3. Then take out the negative of the RHS and we have $Var(max(X,Y)) = Var(min(-X,-Y))$

But from here I'm stuck. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: With $X$ and $Y$ iid $N(0,1)$ variables, $-X$ and $-Y$ are also $N(0,1)$ variables.

Comment: @kimchilover thanks for your help. It makes sense that $-X,-Y$ are also $N(0,1)$. It seems true to me that $(X,Y) \neq (-X,-Y)$  and I get stuck at #3 in my argument above.

Comment: Of course $(X,Y)\ne(-X,-Y)$ but they do have the same distribution, and so do any functions of them, too.  The probability law of $\min(X,Y)$ is the same as that of $\min(-X,-Y)$, and so on.

Comment: Ahhh good point... I have no issue believing $Var(X) = Var(Y) = 1$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent $N(0,1)$ but of course $X \neq Y$ . Thanks for your help